# Do compact connected smooth manifolds admit the structure of a CW complex with a single 1-cell?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

This seems intuitive to me, since they admit a CW decomposition with finitely many cells. But I can't see how to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. Because if you see the cellular homology, then if $X$ has only one 1-cell,  $H_1(X_1,X_0)$ would be a free group of $1$ genarator, but then if yoy compute $H_1(X)$ from cellular homology, then it has only one genarator. But there are many manifold with more than one genarator of $H_1$, for example torus.

Comment: I am so sorry, I meant 0-cell!

Comment: @James you cannot change an entire question like that in MSE, you should post it as a different question. And why cant you check twice before posting your doubts???